# How to call asp.net Web API from android device

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller:

```
// POST: api/CountriesAPI
[ResponseType(typeof(Country))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCountry(Country country)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Countries.Add(country);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = country.CountryID }, country);
}
```

I don't know how how to consume this from android. please help.

Comment: Refer this link. http://hintdesk.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-api-service-from-android/

Comment: Some more links for you http://square.github.io/retrofit/ or http://square.github.io/okhttp/ or https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the Android HTTP Client available [here](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) and found it very simple and easy to use.

You can then do a POST with code something like below:

```
public class HTTPClient 
{
    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
    {
        client.get(url, params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void get(String url, FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
    {
        client.get(url, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void post(Context context, String url, StringEntity entity, String contentType, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
    {
        client.post(context, url, entity, contentType, responseHandler);
    }
}


HTTPClient.post(this, <server_url>, entity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response)
    {
        // Do Something
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable error, String content)
    {
        // Do Something else
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Libraries like Volley (Requires you to write boilerplate code) or [RetroFit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

You can make get and post requests using them, do read about Pojos and model creation before you start. And also how do Callbacks work.

Comment: thank you so much. however I am still not able to call PUT from postman either, can you please provide me a link, etc. thank you.